# Função - mostrar senha!

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, password

Reformulei a pergunta, oque estou tentando fazer é o seguinte, Objetivo é fazer igual o IE faz nos inputs type password!

```
 <style>.show_key{display:none;}</style>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

$(".show_key").mousedown(function() {
    $(".hide-pass-input").attr("type", "text")
});
$(".show_key").mouseup(function() {
    $(".hide-pass-input").attr("type", "password")
}); 
$(".show_key").mouseout(function() {
    $(".hide-pass-input").attr("type", "password")
});


$(".hide-pass-input").keyup(function(){
var num = $(".hide-pass-input").val().length;
if(num>=1){
$(".show_key").show();
}
else{
$(".show_key").hide();  

    }
  });
 });

});
    </script>

    <input  class="hide-pass-input" name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha" value="">

    <div class="show_key">Mostrar senha</div>
```

**Adicionado**

O que preciso é: o input inicia com type password, e se o usuário for digitar  e o campo conter 1 ou mais caracteres a div "show_key" aparece,e clicando nela ela alterar o type password para type text, se eu soltar o show_key ele retorna para type password, e se eu clicar fora do input a div "show_key" some, basicamente a função que aquele ícone de olho que alguns sistemas tem faz para mostrar a senha!

Agradeço a todos.

Comment: Se você colocar o seu if/else dentro de um evento `.change` deve executar do jeito que você quer.

Comment: Por favor se conseguir enviar o código modificado agradeço não sou bom em Js, sei muito, mas muito pouco!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pode fazer apenas com CSS:

```css
.show_key{display:none;}
[name=senha]:focus + .show_key{
   display: block;
   
}
```

```html
<input  class="input" name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha" value="">

<div class="show_key">Mostrar senha</div>
```

Como a div é adjacente ao input, o selector `+ .show_key` irá alterar a sua propriedade ao focar o campo.

### Edit

Usando jQuery para exibir a div quando houver ao menos 1 caractere no campo e mostrar a senha ao clicar na div "Mostrar senha":

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   // captura os eventos keyup e focus no campo
   $("[name=senha]").on("keyup focus", function(){
      // mostra/esconde a div se houver ao menos 1 caractere
      $(".show_key")[ $(this).val().length ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
   });
   
   // captura os eventos de mouse no campo e na div
   $(".show_key, [name=senha]").on("click mousedown mouseup mouseleave", function(e){
      
      // cancela a bubbling do evento click no "document"
      e.stopPropagation();
      // altera o type do campo
      $("[name=senha]")
      .attr("type", e.type == "mousedown" && !$(e.target).hasClass("input") ? "text" : "password");
      
   });
   
   // esconde a div ao clicar em qualquer parte do documento
   $(document).on("click", function(){
      $(".show_key").hide();
   });
});
```

```css
.show_key{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  class="input" name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha" value="">
<div class="show_key">Mostrar senha</div>
```

Comment: Bom crio que com apenas ccs não vai ser possível fazer o que quero pois,  pois quando tiro o Focus e vou tentar clicar no "Mostrar senha" a div some, e precisava que a div só aparecesse se o campo fosse maior que 1 caractere

Comment: Jovem, a pergunta não diz isso.

Comment: Vou modificar todo post!

Comment: Funcionando, apenas não está sumindo show_key se clicar fora do input.. e alterando o type password para text se eu manter pressionado o show_key

Comment: não sabia que era possível fazer isso de mudar qual a função chamada dessa forma @Sam. Obrigado.

Comment: @CaioLourençon resposta alterada. Veja se era isso.

Comment: Vou editar o código, e colocar o que eu tenho exatamente no meu js! O que o código não faz é sumir a div quando clico fora do input!

Comment: Ficou perfeito! Oha não é querendo ser chato não mas no quesito segurança seu código está com uma brecha, vi isso em uma outra postagem e corrigi no meu lá acima, faça o seguinte teste no seu... quando clicar em mostrar senha fique pressionado e arraste o mouse para fora da área da div que mesmo soltando a o botão pressionado a div permanece no type text mostrando a senha!

Comment: @CaioLourençon Boa observação. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @CaioLourençon É só adicionar mais um evento no seletor: `$(".show_key, [name=senha]").on("click mousedown mouseup mouseleave"...`... no caso, o `mouseleave`

Comment: Perfeito, tudo ok!

Comment: Olá, retornando ao mesmo código, No caso acima ,como faria para adicionar uma class com "addClass()" somente quando o type do input for "text" e removeClass quando for type password? grato!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90736/discussion-between-sam-and-caio-lourencon).

Answer (score 6):

Tem uma opção para fazer essa "verificação" apenas com CSS usado a *pseudo-classe* `:placeholder-shown`. Assim vc nem vai precisar de inserir uma classe `.active` no label, pois a verificação é no `input + label` pelo `css`

**Funciona assim:**

Se o `input` tiver um `placeholder` ativo, ou seja, se o `input` estiver vazio apenas com o `placeholder` aparecendo normalmente a `label` que vem a seguir vai ficar com o texto vermelho por exemplo.

Porém, se tiver algo escrito dentro do `input`, ou seja, se o `placeholder` NÃO estiver mais ativo (pois vai ter algo escrito dentro), a opção **"Mostrar Senha"** aparece.

Veja o exemplo abaixo para entender melhor:

```css
input:placeholder-shown + label {
    color: red;
display:none;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
display:block;
}
```

```html
Escreva algo nesse input vai aparecer o "Mostrar Senha"<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="com placeholder / sem value" value="" name="" id="app">
<label for="app">Mostrar Senha</label>

<br>
<br>
<br>

Esse input já tem um valor no value<br>
Apague  o texto do input!<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="meu placeholder" value="com value senha" name="" id="app">
<label for="app">Já aparece o "mostrar senha"</label>
```

**OBS 2: Não** funciona no IE e Edge https://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder-shown

Comment: Olha com puro CSS também é uma boa,ótimo ideia, ficou muito bom.

Comment: E como é que faz pra mostrar a senha? :D

Comment: @Sam seria mais fácil fazer uma função para trocar o tipo do input de password para text, mas ai eh com o povo do js. A intenção minha era mesmo só mostrar o elemento seguinte se tiver algo escrito no input.

Comment: @CaioLourençon valeu jovem, essa solução ajuda, mas para revelar o texto realmente precisa de um js, essa técnica só serve para mostrar o elemento seguinte , caso o input tenha um value

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma, apesar de existirem formas melhores:

```js
$('.input').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#show_key').removeClass('show_key');
    }
});

$('.input').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $('#show_key').addClass('show_key');
    }
});
```

```css
.show_key{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha" value="">

<div id="show_key" class="show_key">Mostrar senha</div>
```

Usando o evento `focus`, sempre que o input receber foco eu removo a classe que esconde a div. E no evento `focusout`, sempre que o foco for para outro nó, adiciona novamente a classe que esconde a div.

Comment: Bom assim resolveu em partes, pois quando tiro o Focus e vou tentar clicar no "Mostrar senha" a div some, e precisava que a div só aparecesse se o campo fosse maior que 1 caractere

Comment: Você não havia especificado isso. Pediu pra div sumir quando o foco saisse do input, e ao clicar na div o foco vai sair do input... Especifique exatamente o que você quer para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Pronto, agora faz o que você quer.

Comment: vou modificar todo post!