# Mudar propriedades do pai se existir filho CSS

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
.react-tagsinput .react-tagsinput-input {
  width: 100% !important;
}

// coloquei aqui apenas para lembrar que existe essa opção caso desejar usar
//.react-tagsinput--focused .react-tagsinput-input {
//  width: 100% !important;
//}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
```

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Defini .react-tagsinput-input como 100% para o placeholder aparecer por inteiro, pois senão estava aparecendo somente com 80px.

Mas ao clicar fora do input, o campo ainda continua existindo em baixo.

O que eu desejo é:
Ao clicar fora do campo, se existir .react-tagsinput-tag como filho, definir .react-tagsinput-input como 0px, ou seja, pra sumir a linha vazia abaixo. Ao clicar novamente, ser definido como 100% de novo.

Existe também .react-tagsinput--focused .react-tagsinput-input caso for necessário usar para o campo clicado.

As duas primeiras imagens estão como eu desejo.

[image: Sem nenhuma tag]

[image: Com tag (Tudo certo por aqui) - class mudou para .react-tagsinput--focused]

[image: PROBLEMA AQUI - ao clicar fora, gostaria que essa linha sumisse se já existe alguma tag ao perder o foco. Ao ganhar foco novamente, ela aparece para ser digitado]

PROBLEMA ESTÁ AQUI NESSA ÚLTIMA IMAGEM - ao clicar fora, gostaria que essa linha sumisse se já existe alguma tag ao perder o foco. Ao ganhar foco novamente, ela aparece para ser digitado novamente.

Comment: Tem algumas formas de fazer sim só com CSS, pelo que entendi se tiver alguma tag ou nada vc quer que a linha tenha uma altura x, se tiver uma tag ou nada e focar a altura é 2x, e no blur volta pra x tendo algo dentro ou não, é isso?

Comment: Na verdade não tem a ver com a altura, mas sim com ela aparecer ou não. O que eu quero é: **fazer sumir o .react-tagsinput-input SE existir alguma .react-tagsinput-tag ao tirar o focus**. Na imagem com a seta vermelha, como perdeu o foco, o certo era sumir o .react-tagsinput-input. Ao clicar novamente, ela deveria aparecer, assim como na 2ª imagem. Se não tiver nenhuma .react-tagsinput-tag, ela também deverá aparecer, pois ela contém o placeholder, como na 1ª imagem. Ou seja, se não existir .react-tagsinput-tag, seja com ou sem foco, .react-tagsinput-input deve aparecer.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que a linha em branco, na verdade apenas não tem o placeholder pois no React fiz a alteração dela caso já existisse algum tag inserida. Portanto, se essa modificação não fosse feita, estaria da seguinte forma: http://prntscr.com/od1mz2. Eu retiro ele para ficar mais bonito. Se der para já fazer isso só no CSS também, é até melhor do que a gambiarra que fiz no Javascript.. hehe Agradeço desde já @hugocsl =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que seu sistema gera um `span` com a `tag` que na verdade fica fora do `input` e não dentro dele, isso dificulta um pouco pra fazer só com CSS, uma alternativa é gerar esse `span` depois do `input` pra facilitar de colocar a tag caso tenha alguma interação no `input` acima.

Agora vamos ao código. O único JS que usei, puro, foi para vc poder focar em um input que está dentro de uma `div` clicando na própria `div`, tirando isso não precisa mais de JS para nada. Então se clicar na `div pai` foca no `input filho` que está dentro ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima, o `span` que vai aparecer com a `tag` fica com `display:block`, e só vai aparecer se o `input` acima tiver algum valor dentro. para fazer essa validação eu uso `:not(placeholder-shown)`, para saber mais leia aqui [Função - mostrar senha!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366605/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mostrar-senha/) que falo um pouco mais sobre isso.

Existe uma propriedade de CSS chamada `:focus-within` ela serve para estilizar um elemento caso algum filho dentro dele seja focado. Isso é nativo do CSS e é com essa *pseudo-classe* que eu coloco a cor na `div` quando `foco` no `input` dentro dela

E para "remover" o input eu concateno a técnica assima com um `:not(focus)`, fica assim `input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus)`. Então se não tiver `placeholder` pq logicamente tem algum valor dentro e não estiver focado, logicamente pq vc clicou fora o `input` some.

Para tirar o `input` da tela eu usei o mesmo CSS que o Bootstrap usa na classe `sr-only`, esse CSS não tira o `input` da tela com `display:none`, pois isso atrapalha a acessibilidade, `sr-only` apenas não deixa o `input` visível para os usuários "normais", mas o `input` continua acessível para os leitores de tela *screen-readers*

Segue o código com o exemplo. tudo com CSS `(js só para focar o input quando clica na div, se vc precisar disso...)`

```js
var pai = document.querySelectorAll('.react-tagsinput');
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('.react-tagsinput-input');

function foca() {
 inp.forEach( (tag) => {
  tag.focus();
 })
}
pai.forEach( (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', foca);
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.react-tagsinput {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.react-tagsinput:focus-within {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.react-tagsinput:focus-within .react-tagsinput-input {
  height: 50px;
}
.react-tagsinput .react-tagsinput-input + span {
  display: none;
}
.react-tagsinput .react-tagsinput-input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span {
  display: block;
}
.react-tagsinput .react-tagsinput-input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus){
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="react-tagsinput">
    <input type="text" class="react-tagsinput-input" placeholder="com placeholder">
    <span class="react-tagsinput-tag">tag</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Não é a toa que sua reputação no CSS aqui no stack é top! haha Sobre o JS que colocou, como estou usando um tema pronto, provavelmente o cara já fez isso, pois ao clicar na div já funciona o input normalmente. Cara, muito obrigado mesmo! =]

Comment: @GleidsonHenrique legal que deu certo ai jovem! Se o script do tema já resolve é melhor não usar o que eu deixei na resposta, ele foi mas para poder montar o exemplo mesmo. E tenha em mente que essas propriedades de CSS são bem novas, e podem não funcionar nos browsers mais antigos... principalmente no IE...[]´s