# Como alterar um elemento após uma ação na página?

Tags: html, css, html-tags

Gostaria de quando conteúdo fosse adicionado ao input o texto anterior "tituloSub" ficasse azul. São dentro de uma div, um p e um input, o objetivo é quando escrever no input o p anterior ficasse azul.

```css
.subInput:nth-child(-1), .subInput:focus{/*Tentei usar isso, mas não deu certo*/
    color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="Subscribe">
  <div id="CxSub1" class="caixadeSubscribe">
   <p class="tituloSub">TITULO. Esse Titulo tem que ficar azul quando escrever no input</p>
   <input id="subInpt1" type="text" name="LoremIpsum" class="subInput" >
  </div>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Como citado em [Mudar propriedades do pai se existir filho CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396378/mudar-propriedades-do-pai-se-existir-filho-css) basta você utilizar o seletor `:focus-within` no elemento pai do seu campo:

```css
.texto-azul:focus-within > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto-azul">
  <p>Este texto ficará azul</p>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado. Aprendi agora essa função "within"

Comment: Valeu a menção :)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito de css, mas sei que pode ser facilmente feito em JavaScript.
Crie um evento para quando o input não estiver vazio então "titulo" ganha um atributo de estilo

```js
function pintaTitulo(){
  var titulo = document.getElementById('titulo');
  var inputContent = document.getElementById('subInpt1').value;
  
  if(inputContent.length > 0){
    titulo.setAttribute("style","color:blue");  
  }
  else{
    titulo.setAttribute("style","color:default");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Subscribe">
  <div id="CxSub1" class="caixadeSubscribe">
    <p class="tituloSub"><span id="titulo">TITULO</span>. Esse Titulo tem que ficar azul quando escrever no input</p>
    <input id="subInpt1" type="text" name="LoremIpsum" class="subInput" oninput="pintaTitulo()" >
  </div>
</div>
```